# difference between X and Xorg executables under Debian 6.0(kernel 2.6.32-5-686)

Tags: xorg, x11

What is the difference between `X` and `Xorg` executables? I have both in /usr/bin directory:

```
# file /usr/bin/Xorg
/usr/bin/Xorg: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
# ls -lh /usr/bin/Xorg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.7M Oct 30  2011 /usr/bin/Xorg
# file /usr/bin/X
/usr/bin/X: setuid setgid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
# ls -lh /usr/bin/X
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 7.1K Dec 16  2011 /usr/bin/X
#
```

I guess that while /usr/bin/X is not symbolic link to /usr/bin/Xorg, it still calls the /usr/bin/Xorg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/bin/X` is the X wrapper. It is documented in the [`Xwrapper.config`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=Xwrapper.config) man page.

The X wrapper is a small program that controls who is authorized to launch the real X server. Only root can launch the real X server because it needs access to the video hardware. The wrapper is setuid root, and by default only allows users logged in on the console to start the real X server.